# Removing values from dictionary that multiple keys share

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates, unique

I've got a dictionary built of `title:substrings` where the first three entries look like:

```
'1' : ['G', 'GA', 'GAA', 'GAAA', 'GAAAA', 'GAAAAA', 'GAAAAAG', 'GAAAAAGU', 'GAAAAAGUA', 'GAAAAAGUAU', 'GAAAAAGUAUG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGC', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAAC']

'2' : ['G', 'GA', 'GAG', 'GAGA', 'GAGAG', 'GAGAGA', 'GAGAGAG', 'GAGAGAGA', 'GAGAGAGAC', 'GAGAGAGACA', 'GAGAGAGACAU', 'GAGAGAGACAUA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAGG']

'3' : ['G', 'GU', 'GUC', 'GUCU', 'GUCUU', 'GUCUUU', 'GUCUUUG', 'GUCUUUGU', 'GUCUUUGU"', 'GUCUUUGU"G', 'GUCUUUGU"GU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUAC', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAUC']
```

I found quite a few answers on how to convert them to lists and creating a for loop to check if items in 1 is in other and if so remove them, but I don't think that's feasible for me since this dictionary is generated and not handwritten by me. Because of that I don't really understand how I should be approaching this problem.

Comment: I've attempted to create a list of the values and attempted to do iteration kind of like "if item[0] in item[1]: d.remove[item[0]" but the logic was wrong in it and spewed out errors

Comment: Lets see if I have this right, if "G" is in 1, 2 and 3, you want it removed from 2 of twohem but to remain in one of them. Do you care which one? Are these values hashable objects like a string?

Comment: @tdelaney if G is in 1,2,3, I want to remove it from 1,2,3 so that at the very end list 1,2, and 3 each contain only the strings that are unique to them (not in other lists). These values are strings, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an index where each value lists the keys it is in. If that list is greater than 1, remove that value.

```
mydict = {
'1' : ['G', 'GA', 'GAA', 'GAAA', 'GAAAA', 'GAAAAA', 'GAAAAAG', 'GAAAAAGU', 'GAAAAAGUA', 'GAAAAAGUAU', 'GAAAAAGUAUG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGC', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAAC'],

'2' : ['G', 'GA', 'GAG', 'GAGA', 'GAGAG', 'GAGAGA', 'GAGAGAG', 'GAGAGAGA', 'GAGAGAGAC', 'GAGAGAGACA', 'GAGAGAGACAU', 'GAGAGAGACAUA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAGG'],

'3' : ['G', 'GU', 'GUC', 'GUCU', 'GUCUU', 'GUCUUU', 'GUCUUUG', 'GUCUUUGU', 'GUCUUUGU"', 'GUCUUUGU"G', 'GUCUUUGU"GU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUAC', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAUC']
}

# build a dict of values and the keys that hold them
tmpdict = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in mydict.items():
    for value in values:
        tmpdict[value].append(key)

# now remove offenders from the original list
for value, inkeys in tmpdict.items():
    if len(inkeys) > 1:
        for key in inkeys:
            mydict[key].remove(value)

print mydict
```

Comment: Thank you so much tdelaney! this worked perfectly. Could I ask you how I would go about removing items in one list that go "GAAAA" since GAAAA is just an extension of GAA (which is already in the list at the beginning)?

Comment: You may be able to hack it into `tmpdict[value].append(key)`  depending on what your rules for what really is an extension. If it was as easy as "I only care about the first 3 letters" then it would be `tmpdict[value[:3]].append(key)`. What are the rules for knowing when its an extension? You probably don't want "GAA" to be an extension of "G".

Comment: basically after removing all reoccuring strings, the lists always start with the smallest first unique string. so in list 1 that would be GAA, but then you've got the next however many strings as just additions of more As on top of GAA. So GAA would be used as the basis on if the others need to be removed. so if it is GAA[+other letters] it would be counted as an extension and removed

Answer (score 0):

Removing arbitrary items from lists leads to poor performance when you need to scale. It's usually better to make new lists from the old and leave out the items you wanted to remove.

Here, the items you wish to remove are values that have a count greater than 1

```
>>> mydict = {
... '1' : ['G', 'GA', 'GAA', 'GAAA', 'GAAAA', 'GAAAAA', 'GAAAAAG', 'GAAAAAGU', 'GAAAAAGUA', 'GAAAAAGUAU', 'GAAAAAGUAUG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGC', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAAC'],
... '2' : ['G', 'GA', 'GAG', 'GAGA', 'GAGAG', 'GAGAGA', 'GAGAGAG', 'GAGAGAGA', 'GAGAGAGAC', 'GAGAGAGACA', 'GAGAGAGACAU', 'GAGAGAGACAUA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAGG'],
... '3' : ['G', 'GU', 'GUC', 'GUCU', 'GUCUU', 'GUCUUU', 'GUCUUUG', 'GUCUUUGU', 'GUCUUUGU"', 'GUCUUUGU"G', 'GUCUUUGU"GU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUAC', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAUC']
... }
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(mydict.values()))
>>> {k: [x for x in v if c[x] == 1] for k, v in mydict.items()}
{'1': ['GAA', 'GAAA', 'GAAAA', 'GAAAAA', 'GAAAAAG', 'GAAAAAGU', 'GAAAAAGUA', 'GAAAAAGUAU', 'GAAAAAGUAUG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGC', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAAC'],
 '3': ['GU', 'GUC', 'GUCU', 'GUCUU', 'GUCUUU', 'GUCUUUG', 'GUCUUUGU', 'GUCUUUGU"', 'GUCUUUGU"G', 'GUCUUUGU"GU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUAC', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAUC'], 
 '2': ['GAG', 'GAGA', 'GAGAG', 'GAGAGA', 'GAGAGAG', 'GAGAGAGA', 'GAGAGAGAC', 'GAGAGAGACA', 'GAGAGAGACAU', 'GAGAGAGACAUA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAGG']}
```